# Filter result doesn't match with result

Tags: android, expandablelistview, searchview

This code has completely work here is the code:

This is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tesskian;



import java.util.ArrayList;




import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
 SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener{

 private SearchView search;
 private mylistadapter listAdapter;
 private ExpandableListView myList;
 private ArrayList<continent> continentList = new ArrayList<continent>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
  search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
  search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
  search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
  search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
  search.setOnCloseListener(this);

  //display the list
  displayList();
  //expand all Groups
  expandAll();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //method to expand all groups
 private void expandAll() {
  int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
   myList.expandGroup(i);
  }
 }

 //method to expand all groups
 private void displayList() {

  //display the list
  loadSomeData();

  //get reference to the ExpandableListView
  myList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
  //create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
  listAdapter = new mylistadapter(MainActivity.this, continentList);
  //attach the adapter to the list
  myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);



 myList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (groupPosition == 0 ) {
                if (childPosition == 0){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cont.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), con1.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), schema.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }


                if (childPosition == 3) {
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ajax.class);
             startActivity(i);
                }

                if (childPosition == 4) {
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), examples.class);
             startActivity(i);
                }
            }
                if (groupPosition == 1) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), overview.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), arrai.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), bool.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), object.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), number.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 5) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), string.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 6) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tru.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 7) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), fals.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 8) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nulll.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }


            }

        return false;
        }
    });
}


 private void loadSomeData() {

  ArrayList<country> countryList = new ArrayList<country>();
  country country = new country("Introduction");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Data Types");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Schema");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Use In Ajax");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Examples");
  countryList.add(country);

  continent continent = new continent("Basics",countryList);
  continentList.add(continent);

  countryList = new ArrayList<country>();
  country = new country("Overview");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Array");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Boolean");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Object");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Number");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("String");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("False");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("True");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Null");
  countryList.add(country);

  continent = new continent("Data Types",countryList);
  continentList.add(continent);

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onClose() {
  listAdapter.filterData("");
  expandAll();
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
  listAdapter.filterData(query);
  expandAll();
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
  listAdapter.filterData(query);
  expandAll();
  return false;
 }
}
```

This is MyListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.tesskian;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class mylistadapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

 private Context context;
 private ArrayList<continent> continentList;
 private ArrayList<continent> originalList;

 public mylistadapter(Context context, ArrayList<continent> continentList) {
  this.context = context;
  this.continentList = new ArrayList<continent>();
  this.continentList.addAll(continentList);
  this.originalList = new ArrayList<continent>();
  this.originalList.addAll(continentList);
 }

 @Override
 public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
  ArrayList<country> countryList = continentList.get(groupPosition).getCountryList();
  return countryList.get(childPosition);
 }

 @Override
 public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
  return childPosition;
 }

 @Override
 public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, 
   View view, ViewGroup parent) {

  country country = (country) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
  if (view == null) {
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
  }

  TextView code = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.code);

  code.setText(country.getCode().trim());


  return view;
 }

 @Override
 public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

  ArrayList<country> countryList = continentList.get(groupPosition).getCountryList();
  return countryList.size();

 }

 @Override
 public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
  return continentList.get(groupPosition);
 }

 @Override
 public int getGroupCount() {
  return continentList.size();
 }

 @Override
 public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
  return groupPosition;
 }

 @Override
 public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
   ViewGroup parent) {

  continent continent = (continent) getGroup(groupPosition);
  if (view == null) {
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
  }

  TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
  heading.setText(continent.getName().trim());

  return view;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean hasStableIds() {
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
  return true;
 }

 public void filterData(String query){

  query = query.toLowerCase();
  Log.v("MyListAdapter", String.valueOf(continentList.size()));
  continentList.clear();

  if(query.isEmpty()){
   continentList.addAll(originalList);
  }
  else {

   for(continent continent: originalList){

    ArrayList<country> countryList = continent.getCountryList();
    ArrayList<country> newList = new ArrayList<country>();
    for(country country: countryList){
     if(country.getCode().toLowerCase().contains(query) ||
       country.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)){
      newList.add(country);
     }
    }
    if(newList.size() > 0){
     continent nContinent = new continent(continent.getName(),newList);
     continentList.add(nContinent);
    }
   }
  }

  Log.v("MyListAdapter", String.valueOf(continentList.size()));
  notifyDataSetChanged();

 }

}
```

This is Continent.java

```
package com.example.tesskian;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class continent {

 private String name;
 private ArrayList<country> countryList = new ArrayList<country>();

 public continent(String name, ArrayList<country> countryList) {
  super();
  this.name = name;
  this.countryList = countryList;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public ArrayList<country> getCountryList() {
  return countryList;
 }
 public void setCountryList(ArrayList<country> countryList) {
  this.countryList = countryList;
 };


}
```

This is Counter.java

```
package com.example.tesskian;

public class country {

     private String code = "";
     private String name = "";
     private int population = 0;

     public country(String code) {
      super();
      this.code = code;
      this.name = name;
      this.population = population;
     }

     public String getCode() {
      return code;
     }
     public void setCode(String code) {
      this.code = code;
     }
     public String getName() {
      return name;
     }
     public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
     }
     public int getPopulation() {
      return population;
     }
     public void setPopulation(int population) {
      this.population = population;
     }

    }
```

it's working but when i starting to filter it with searchview the trouble is coming. The activity has started but it is not match with activity what i search. For example i am looking for "example" but if i click it's show first activity "cont.class". Can someone help me?